# Program to convert Excel 2013 spreadsheets to LaTeX tables

Tags: latex, microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a program or web-service that

- can convert Microsoft Excel 2013 spreadsheets to LATEX tables

And if possible:

- free
- works on Windows 7

The package [Excel-to-LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex) only works for Ex­cel 2010 and earlier versions.

Comment: I don't have experience with Excel 2013, but are the spreadsheets really that different? If not, you could just save the file as 2010 version and then do the conversion

Comment: I just had the idea how to write such a tool, but: What are your expections? Only a simple table with easy rows and columns? Or complex tables with combined columns (\multicolumn in LaTeX) and rows. Any Colors in cells? Any formatting? Detect Header lines?

Comment: I created a program and I think it should be able to concert Excel 2013 files into LaTeX tabulars. But I have no Excel 2013, so I can't check it myself. Can you try [xlsx2latex.exe](https://github.com/knut2/xlsx2latex/releases/tag/V0.1.0.rc2) with your file? Just download it and try `xlsx2latex <your xlsx-file>`. If you confirm it works with Excel 2013 files I will post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the way via an *intermediate CSV file* is OK, I suggest the following workflow:

#### Conversion from Excel to CSV

Use [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv), a python script which is small, efficient and fast. In the most easiest case (Excel file with one sheet) you could get away with the command line:

> python xlsx2csv.py data.xslx data.csv

#### Conversion from CSV to Markdown

Use [csvtomd](https://github.com/mplewis/csvtomd), another python script to get you to the [Markdown format](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). Unfortunately it is a Python 3 script, so you need a separate Python 3 environment.(*) The command line here is:

```
> python3 path/to/your/csvtomd-dir/csvtomd.py  data.csv >data.md
```

#### Conversion from CSV to LaTeX

Use the excellent [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). Install it properly and make sure you have it on your path. Then call it like this:

```
> pandoc -f markdown -t latex -o data.tex data.md
```

And - voila! - if everything went well, `data.tex` contains your Excel table as a LaTeX table.(+) BTW, all tools mentioned work perfectly on Windows 7.

---

(*)  You can use e.g. [Anconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) to have Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 next to each other.

(+) Please note, `pandoc` uses the flexible [`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package to format its tables.